# Make Entity Framework read-only

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, readonly

I'm currently creating an application that extracts data from lots of different data sources - most of these are development databases but some are live (I understand this is awful, but it's completely out of my control).

I'd like to protect myself from making modifications to these live databases, I'm therefore interested in making entities **read-only**.

My research tells me this isn't possible, but I'm anticipating a feature change or work-around may be available now.  Has anyone achieved this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that it's better to put that limit in the database instead of in the application. Create a separate user in the live database, that is member of the `data_reader` role. That will give read access only to the database.

If you've tweaked the security settings and roles on the server you have to check more in detail, but as a default `data_reader` will do.

#### Edit

A simple way to do it would be to override the `SaveChanges()` method of the data context for those databases:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    throw new AccessViolationException(
         "Don't mess with a live database during test");
}
```

Comment: I understand and would put that limit in the database - however I have no control over this hence my question.

Comment: Ok, sometimes the best way is not possible. Please see my edit with an idea of overriding `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: Thanks for that - I'm assuming the tools will remove this when refreshing the model however?

Comment: @m.edmondson put the override in your own part of the `partial` context class, and the designer won't interfere with it.

Comment: @AakashM - The only part of the partial class I can find is the one generated by the tool, can you elaborate where this is?

Comment: @m.edmondson: Create an own file which contains another `partial class MyDbContext {}`. When they are declared partial, they will be merged into one class during compile, but your separate file won't be overwritten by code generation.

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to be partial with the wrong class, got this confirmed working now.  Thanks very much.